# How to get the exactly Money with format from SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, culture

I want to get the `Money` value just like it is in SQL, but Visual Studio changes it to another region currency format.

The SQL stored procedure formats the `Money` like this:

```
select Format(Pagos.Monto,'L\.#,##0.00') as Cuota 
from Pagos
```

I'm getting the data on `VB` like this:

```
    Try
        conectar() 'This just connects 
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn) 
        Dim ds As New DataSet    
        da.Fill(ds) 
        dv.Table = ds.Tables(0) 'Loads the table result on a DataView
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message) 
    Finally 
        desconectar() 'This just disconnects
    End Try
```

(I know that I'm not executing the stored procedure properly, but that doesn't matter right now).

I'm expecting to get something like: `L.12,750.00`

But instead Visual Studio returns: `L.12.750,00`

I've already tried all this in different ways:

```
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-HN")
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-HN")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-HN")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-HN")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-HN")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ","
```

But nothing has worked for me.

I just want to get it exactly like it is in SQL. Thanks

Comment: _Visual returns: L.12.750,00_ Where do you see this? Are you looking at it on a form? Are you inspecting the variable at runtime?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to format a piece of data in a stored procedure. You should really leave it as it's base data type (money) then format it in the app

Comment: The query is returning a string. The value of that string will not be changed, so the string must be wrong directly from the database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I can see Visual changing the format when executing the query, inspecting the DataTable, but also on a DataGridView on my form of course.

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, trust me, Visual changes the value, on Sql it looks how it's supposed to. I checked everything